# Mapping column data based on the id using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, mapping

[csv sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgl78.png) create a path using path and child category id such that the column f will be like
accesories.belts
accsories.belt_buckles

data

```
cat_id  Category    path    child category id   child_category
1   Accessories     1               1           Accessories
1   Accessories     1, 2            2           Belts & Suspenders
1   Accessories     1, 2, 3         3           Belt Buckles
1   Accessories     1, 2, 4         4           Belts
1   Accessories     1, 2, 5         5           Suspenders
1   Accessories     1, 6            6           Costume Accessories
    desired
cat_id  Category    path    child category id   child_category          category path
1   Accessories     1               1           Accessories             accessories
1   Accessories     1, 2            2           Belts & Suspenders      accessories > Belts & Suspenders
1   Accessories     1, 2, 3         3           Belt Buckles            accessories > Belts & Suspenders > Belts & Buckles
1   Accessories     1, 2, 4         4           Belts                   accessories > Belts & Suspenders > Belts 
1   Accessories     1, 2, 5         5           Suspenders              accessories > Belts & Suspenders > Suspenders
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create a `dict` to link ids to categories:

```
dic = dict(zip(df['child category id'], df['child_category']))
```

Then with the use of `.split()`, `dict.get()` and `.join()` you can obtain your desired column:

```
def repl(x,dic=dic):
    y = ' > '.join([dic.get(int(i),int(i)) for i in x.split(',')])
    return y

df['new_col'] = df['path'].apply(lambda x: repl(x))
```